# Dynamic Select Box in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am a newbie to Ruby on Rails . I have started working on RoR 1 month back.
My problem is:

I have a single table called syscode which has Id ,Name ,Desc and Parent_id .
For parent the Parent_id=0 and for childs they have parent_id according to the id of the parent.

I should have two select boxes in which the first select box should display the parents and the second select box should be dynamic i.e On click of parent in the first select box it should display the respective childs in the second select box.
I am successful in getting the parent_id on click of the options in the first select box.

The code i have tried is:

View : selectnew.html.erb

```
<div id="dvSelectSyscodeForm">  
  <%= form_for(@syscode) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="syscode_fksyscodeparent">Parent</label>
      <%= f.select :fksyscodeparent, Syscode.where("fksyscodeparent = '0'").map {|s| ["#{s.syscode}", s.id ]} %>
    </div>
    <div id="dvShowChild" style="display:none;">
      <div class="field">
        <label for="childSyscodes">Child</label>
        <%= f.select :fksyscodeparent, Syscode.where("fksyscodeparent = '0'").map {|s| ["#{s.syscode}", s.id ]} %>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var scode = [];
      function parentSelected() {        
        parent_id = $('#syscode_fksyscodeparent').val();
        alert(parent_id);          
      }    

      $(document).ready(function() {
        parentSelected();
        $('#syscode_fksyscodeparent').change(parentSelected);
      });

    </script>
    <% end %>  
    </div>
    <%= link_to 'Back', syscodes_path %>
```

## Controller : selectnew

```
def selectnew
  @syscode = Syscode.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # selectnew.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @syscode }
  end
end
```

Please help me guys ... Thank You in Advance ...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do an Ajax call in your parentSelected function. The return from this Ajax call should be javascript that replaces the content of "dvShowChild" with new html content for the currently selected parent.

Alternatively you could do an ajax call that fetches html and then in the success callback replace the html value of "dvShowChild" with the html returned from the ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .... I want my first dropdown always to be the parent .. On selection of parent it should display the second dropdown with its childs ..

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. when you select something in the first selector you change the content of the second selector in one of the ways i mention above. Send the parent ID with the ajax call and use it when constructing the return javascript or html template.

Comment: I am not getting how to do it in ruby on rails ... Please help by posting a sample code ...

Comment: Thanks EasyPush ... I followed the way you have guided me and i succeeded in getting the result after a long struggle of 2 days ...

Comment: Sorry i couldn't post example code, didn't have any available on the spot. But i'm glad you solved it. I might be even more glad if you accept my answer though ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following steps - 
Step -1 In your view file 
    parent select box

```
= f.select :parent_id, @parent_val,  data: { remote: true, url: update_children_url}
child select box

= f.select :child_id, @child_values.present? ? @child_values : [], {prompt: 'Select' }
```

Step -2 
    create update_children.js.erb file in your views folder
    and write down the following code -

```
 $("#child_id").html("#{j options_for_select(@child_values)}")
```

Step - 3 
  In your controller

```
def update_children
  return values @child_values
end
```